# .NET How to run http server in same process as listening to servicebus

Tags: c#, multithreading, owin

I'm trying to add HTTP functionality to an already existing application which is 'listening' for events sent by an event hub.

The event listener is working asynchronously and is initialized like so:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (string hub in hubs) {
            tasks.Add(ReceiveMessagesHubAsync(hub, cancel.Token));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

I'm using WebApi and OWIN-SelfHost to create my HTTP server. This starts up like so:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Web server running at: {0}", baseAddress);
    Thread.Sleep(-1);
}
```

The webserver doesn't respond if I also listen for events. If I disable the event listening (comment out the `Task.WaitAll()` operation) then the webserver does work.

I tried moving the `WebApp.Start` before the asynchronous event hub code and remove the `Thread.Sleep()` operation, but this also blocks the webserver from functioning.

Now I understand that this is a threading problem but I don't know exactly how to solve it. Should I execute the webserver initialization in a new thread? Or is there some other (built-in) way and am I over-complicating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) I saw, there shouldn't be anything special other than making sure all your logic is inside the `using` statement.

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Web server running at: {0}", baseAddress);

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string hub in hubs) {
        tasks.Add(ReceiveMessagesHubAsync(hub, cancel.Token));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

Console.WriteLine ("Web server shut dow");
```

As soon as you go outside the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement, your `WebApp` will get disposed and it will no longer listen for events.  If the way your class is structured doesn't lend itself to keeping everything inside one `using` statement, then you can store the `WebApp` as a class variable and when your whole class is getting disposed, you just dispose of that `WebApp` instance as well.

Comment: Stupid I disregarded the disposing of the `WebApp` in my restructuring. Works like a charm now, thanks!